# Infix to Postfix conversion - segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack

I'm getting a segmentation fault saying core dumped . The C++ program is to covert an infix expression. I guess the logic is correct. I've checked the code, but can't figure out the error.
I have the precedence function to calculate the precedence of a operator and the the function ifpf converts the infix expression to postfix expression.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 100
using namespace std;
class stack{
    char pstack[size];
    int top;
    public:
    stack(){
        int top=-1;
    }
    void push(char item){
        if(top==size) {cout<<"Stack is already full";exit(0);}
        else {pstack[++top]=item;}
    }
    char pop(){
        char ch='#';
        if(top==-1) cout<<"Stack is empty...";
        else { ch=pstack[top--];}
        return ch;
    }
    int precedence(char ch){
        switch(ch){
            case '(' : return 1;
            case ')' : return 2;
            case '+' :
            case '-' : return 3;
            case '*' :
            case '/' :
            case '%' : return 4;
            case '^' : return 5;
            default : return 0;
        }
    }
    void ifpf(){
        int len,priority,i,j=0;
        char infix[size],ch,postfix[size];
        cout<<"Enter the infix expression : "<<endl;
        cin>>infix;
        len=strlen(infix);
        infix[len++]=')';
        push('(');
        for(i=0,j=0;i<len;i++){
            switch(precedence(infix[i])){
                case 1 : push(infix[i]);break;
                case 2 : ch=pop();
                while(ch!='('){
                    postfix[j++]=ch;ch=pop();
                }
                break;
                case 3 : ch=pop();
                while(precedence(ch)>=3){
                    postfix[j++]=ch;ch=pop();
                }
                push(ch);
                push(infix[i]);
                break;
                case 4 : ch=pop();
                while(precedence(ch)>=4){
                    postfix[j++]=ch;ch=pop();
                }
                push(ch);
                push(infix[i]);
                break;
                case 5 : ch=pop();
                while(precedence(ch)==5){
                    postfix[j++]=ch;ch=pop();
                }
                push(ch);
                push(infix[i]);
                break;
                default : postfix[j++]=infix[i];break;
            }
        }
        cout<<"The post fix wxpression is : ";
        cout<<postfix;
    }
};
int main(){
    stack obj;
    obj.ifpf();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you found out already? Have you tried anything on your own? And would you be so kind to fix your indendation?

Comment: @Mikhail: HTML entities are not used in verbatim code (i.e. don't use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to say `<` and `>`). Apart from that, thanks.

Comment: @phresnel Yeah, I noticed that sorry.

Comment: @Anirudh: Why don't you use standard containers? Also, do not use #defines like `size`, use constants or enums for that. Every occurence of `size` is replaced by `100`, producing invalid code like `std::vector<int> m; m.size() ---> m.100()`

Comment: @Anirudh: Also, it is better to not use `exit()`. With `exit()`, you are skipping destructors.

Comment: Yes, Sir . I do get your point. I'll avoid using exit(). With regard to containers , I didn't try it out. I'll give it a go. Even after removing the #define, I don't seem to get the desired o/p.

Comment: @AnirudhRaja: And the rest, what have you tried, why no standard containers, where does the segfault happen, and and and. The quality of this sunday morning's questions is fascinating and does not quite motivate me to provide useful answers.

Comment: @AnirudhRaja: Okay, Anirudh: One can see on your profile page that you have been here several times after asking your question. Yet you ignore all commenters, this is impolite and I lost interest in spending any more time on this.

Comment: No, sir . I've been trying out the comments that seem to come up . Since I'm working on two things ie. seeing the page and working on the code , it became a bit difficult to concentrate.

Comment: @phresnel I was trying to debug the program , but since I'm new to linux and g++ , I was browsing on how to do so.

Comment: @AnirudhRaja: Before I finally leave StackOverflow for today (frustration about the general quality of questions here), do like the others do and put `@<username>` into the comment so `<username>` becomes noticed about your comment. Otherwise, `<username>` might never see you answered. Bye bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are not setting `top` properly, in your constructor you declared a local `top` which left **stack::top uninitialized**.

```
 stack(){
        int top=-1;  //
    }
```

update to below code, should work:

```
   stack() {
        top = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first bug:

```
if(top==size) {cout<<"Stack is already full";exit(0);}
else {pstack[++top]=item;}
```

That should be:

```
if(top==size-1) {cout<<"Stack is already full";exit(0);}
else {pstack[++top]=item;}
```